# Why I am getting the below error for Selenium "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the mentioned error while executing the code :

```
package Sample_selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selenium_test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver","C:\\Users\\jsivanraj\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        // Open Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Close browser
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

**Note**: I am using the chrome browser version 69.0.3497. Can somebody please help me what i  can do?

Comment: Probably a typo in the key, see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: It should be ~System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\jsivanraj\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");~

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo error. You miss out the ".driver"

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\jsivanraj\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer John.Its the typo error.